# Snowflake sqlalchemy single sign-on without external browser

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flask-restful

I'm creating a flask api which I'll use to access data from snowflake. I'm using snowflake-sqlalchemy library to connect with the datawarehouse. My organization has single sign-on enabled to login into snowflake. As as now, my code for creating engine of sqlalchemy looks like this -

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import settings

engine = create_engine(
            settings.SNOWFLAKE_URI,
            connect_args={
                'authenticator': 'externalbrowser',
                }
            )
connection = engine.connect()
```

But this opens up an external browser to authenticate for snowflake. Is there any other way that can be used so that the browser doesn't get open every time I create a new connection?

Comment: settings is my custom module for storing credentials

Comment: Only for Okta you can do native SSO, otherwise **externalbrowser** is your option. You can use connection caching to minimize authentication prompts but should be checked with your security team.